# Distribution of balls in different boxes and each containing a different number of balls

Tags: combinatorics

I know the answer to this question but I don't know how to show the work for it so any help would be appreciated. : Is it possible to distribute 44 balls into 9 boxes with no box left empty and each containing different number of balls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The conditions are that no box must be empty and that every box must have a different number of balls. There are $9$ boxes. Now, to begin filling the boxes, let a box be chosen. The minimum number of balls that can go into it is $1$. Let one ball be kept in that box. Then, let another box be chosen. Now, the number of balls cannot be either zero or one. The minimum is $2$. Put two balls in this box. Similarly, for the $k^{th}$ box filled, the minimum number of balls that would have to be put in it to satisfy the conditions is $k$. Thus, the minimum number of balls we would need to fill up $9$ boxes would be $$\sum_{k=1}^9 k=45$$

As we have only $44$ balls available, this is not possible.